# Using PHP DOM parser to get data from Javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, html, parsing, dom

I'm learning about parsers and after taking a look at Java parser JSoup I'm trying to do the same with PHP. I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM (don't now if it's the best solution) to get some data from an url, but without success. How can I take the 8 (near bar1) and 18 (near bar0) numbers from the next code from external web using a PHP parser?

```
 <table>

 <tr><td><div name='divns6' id='divns6' style='position:relative;visibility:hidden;'       
    width='400' height='160'><table valign=botton cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' 
    border='0'><tr     valign='bottom'>
  <td width=15 valign="bottom" height=150><a href="javascript:void(null)" 
         onMouseOver="changeImage('bar1','','47',2);activadiv('bar0','18');" 
         onMouseOut="changeImage('bar1','','47',0);desactivadiv('bar1');"><img 
         NAME="barra1" width="11px" height="47" border="0"></a></td>

  <td width=15 valign="bottom" height=150><a href="javascript:void(null)" 
         onMouseOver="changeImage('bar2','','21',2);activadiv('bar1','8');" 
         onMouseOut="changeImage('bar2','','21',0);desactivadiv('bar2');"><img 
         NAME="barra2" width="11px" height="21" border="0"></a></td>

  </td></tr></table>
```

Here's what I've tried, but It only shows the entire line, not only the number:

```
<?php include ("simple_html_dom.php"); 

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.myurl.com');


// Find all text blocks 


$ret = $html->find('a[onMouseOver]');



for ($count='0'; $count<count($ret);$count++) {

echo $ret[$count];


}




?>
```

With JSoup the line who do the trick was: String onMouseOver = doc.select("a").attr("onMouseOver");

Thank you in advance for your time and dedication.

Comment: the markup has a few issues, what is in `simple_html_dom.php`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Andrew. Simple_html_dom.php It's a library from  PHP Simple HTML parser. Finally I've found the solution to my problem. Thanks a lot for your post :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the solution on my own!!

```
<?php include ("simple_html_dom.php"); 

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.myweb.com');


 // Find all text blocks 


 $ret = $html->find('a[onMouseOver]');



 for ($count='0'; $count<count($ret);$count++) {

       echo split("'", $ret[$count])[9]." ";



}




?>
```